# Enable disabled usb ports

Tags: usb, windows, webcam

I have been having a problem with my built-in camera and i start to think that maybe its a usb port issue..

I think, maybe, 4 years ago i disabled on **windows** the usb port of my camera... I dont remember for sure if and what i did. but maybe i did it in the interface of windows,

Currently on my computer i have only Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a few questions:

- is there a way to find out the status of that usb port?
- is there a way to enable it through Ubuntu?

I've had this issue since 4 years, so i got to google it quite a lot. I tried all the Ubuntu answers, and nothing worked, but there were a few cases where getting the camera to work on windows solved the problem on Ubuntu as well, and a few where turning back on the usb port required windows..
following these clues:

- Would installing a vm of windows - could i renable the usb port
  there?
- or i have to install proper windows on my computer?

Thank a lot for any answers :)

---edit--- as been suggested, maybe its disabled in the bios.
I don't have usb legacy support there
my bios is phoenix secure technology, bios version: 0NCN27S2.
I have on boot screen the option of `boot mode` currently on UEFI but optional Legacy support - should I change for that?

Here are images of the three screens I have in my bios

https://snipboard.io/jJy8qW.jpg -- configuration options

https://snipboard.io/dfT5Mg.jpg -- security options

https://snipboard.io/Kz6F08.jpg -- boot options

Comment: I also guessed, and i tried checking my bios. but in my bios i dont have advance options. and i dont manage to get the advanced options to see the status and maybe fix.. is there a way to see the bios config through ubuntu?

Comment: see if the answer works :)

Comment: I looked around, i think the advanced options were completely removed from my bios by Lenovo, so no way to check those settings. i am trying to install windows and get access to device manager.. but its not easy..

Answer (score 0):

- is there a way to find out the status of that usb port?
- is there a way to enable it through Ubuntu?

This will list usb devices:

```
for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device; cat $device;done
```

Example:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/product
HP Wide Vision HD Camera
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product
xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product
xHCI Host Controller
```

If the device is in there take note of the digits and do (assuming 1-6):

```
sudo -i
echo '1-6' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

and that enables it from inside Ubuntu

- Would installing a vm of windows - could i renable the usb port there?

No

- or i have to install proper windows on my computer?

That could do it. But before you do that: have a look at your BIOS. That is the only place something you changed from within Windows that can remain active when you remove Windows. Look for "Legacy USB Support". If unsure please edit the question and add bios name and version number.

Comment: Hi, i tried to bind it before i posted this question, but it didnt seem to help.
I have the legacy support option on my bios, but i didnt think it was related. 
I have Phoenix Technologies bios, not sure the version, i will check and add more info! Thnaks you!!

Comment: That is an indication you have a problem outside of the OS. So hardware related and not software.

Comment: I added more info to my question.